VSCODE Remote Development using SSH: how to open files owned by root
I am VSCODE Remote Development using SSH explained here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh
I ssh to a remote server as an admin user that has root right.
VSCODE can not view/edit files that are owned by root. But I can view them in terminal using sudo
How can I have VSCODE view/edit files using sudo ?
The following annotated screenshot visualizes the question:

